# Multiple XSD schema files to C# classes

Tags: c#, xsd

What is the best way to generate C# classes from multiple XSD schema files?

Some XSD schema files may have dependency to the other, I am trying to avoid duplicated C# classes being generated.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the XSD.EXE program, but pass *all* of the schemas to the program on the same command line.

For example:

```
> xsd /c qbxmltypes130.xsd QBUqbxmlops130.xsd QBUqbxmlso130.xsd QBUqbxml130.xsd
```

Will emit a class named:

```
qbxmltypes130_QBUqbxmlops130_QBUqbxmlso130_QBUqbxml130.cs
```

In this case these are Quickbooks Desktop SDK xsd files, and the final file has types it depends on in the first 3 files. It won't emit on its own, but with its dependencies it works as desired.

Note that there is a `/parameters:<file>` switch that allows you to specify a file of command line parameters. I remember using it in one project for a similar reason.

[XSD.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) doc has the parameter format.

Comment: Just adding an example



"xsd.exe /classes /n:{your_namespace} {file1}.xsd {file2}.xsd {file3}.xsd /out:{your output folder}"

Comment: No need to use Altova XML Spy for generating C# classes from XSDs with multiple references from now on.

Comment: A final addition to the excellent example @vivekp gave: The last file named in the sequence seems to be the one used for generating the class file name. So his example would produce the class file {your output folder}\{file3}.cs

Comment: Gives an error and doesn't generate classes if you have circular group references.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer.

Answer (score 36):

I for one found the examples in the MSDN doc a bit lacking.
Here's an example parameters file for the issue codemeit described:

```
<xsd xmlns='http://microsoft.com/dotnet/tools/xsd/'>
<generateClasses language='CS' namespace='Namespace.subnamespace'>
    <schema>FirstSchema.xsd</schema>
    <schema>AnotherSchema.xsd</schema>
    <schema>LastSchema.xsd</schema>
</generateClasses>
</xsd>
```

Comment: Thanks, @anony_mouse -- I was looking for a good example of that syntax!

Comment: if you get the error "specified path or file name too long" try placing a ".\" infront of the last file and it resolves the problem, note that the output file will then be named by the last file..

Comment: Might be worth mentioning this file has to have the .xml extension and not .xsd. Battled for a bit there, and my includes are over 50. But managed to get it working, it only took 2 seconds to generate