# Xsd.exe with multiple schemas - Meaningful Use Stage 3 - 170.315.f.4 – Transmission to Cancer Registries

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, schema, xsd.exe

I've tried generating classes from the schema files contained in the zip from here:

http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=383

It doesn't matter if a file is included or imported. It will throw an error that it can't find a type or element.

Any idea how this could be done successfully?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140495/multiple-xsd-schema-files-to-c-sharp-classes

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

`xsd /c /n:CCD_SDTC "C:\...\CDA_SDTC.xsd" "C:\...\SDTC.xsd"`